# Airflow DAGS Orchestration

Tags: python, airflow, databricks, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have three DAGs (say, DAG1, DAG2 and DAG3). I have a monthly scheduler for DAG1. DAG2 and DAG3 must not be run directly (no scheduler for these) and must be run only when DAG1 is completed successfully. That is, once DAG1 is complete, DAG2 and DAG3 will need to start in parallel.

What is the best mechanism to do this? I came across TriggerDAGRun and ExternalTaskSensor options. I am wanting to understand the pros and cons of each and which one is the best. I see few questions around these. However, I am trying to find the  answer for the latest stable Airflow version.

Comment: If all tasks are Databricks tasks, then I would suggest to create a job consisting of multiple tasks, and trigger it from Airflow as one object. You'll also get better performance because of the cluster reuse

Answer (score 0):

`ExternalTaskSensor` is not relevant for your use case as none of the DAGs you mention needs to wait for another DAG.

You need to set `TriggerDagRunOperator` at the code of DAG1 that will trigger the DAG runs for DAG2, DAG3.

A skeleton of the solution would be:

```
dag2 = DAG(dag_id="DAG2", schedule_inteval=None)
dag3 = DAG(dag_id="DAG3", schedule_inteval=None)

with DAG(dag_id="DAG1", schedule_inteval="@monthly") as dag1:

    op_first = DummyOperator(task_id="first") #Replace with operators of your DAG
    op_trig2 = TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id="trigger_dag2", trigger_dag_id="DAG2")
    op_trig3 = TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id="trigger_dag3", trigger_dag_id="DAG3")

    op_first >> [op_trig2, op_trig3]
```

**Edit:**
After discussing in comments and since you mentioned you can not edit DAG1 as it's someone else code your best option is `ExternalTaskSensor`. You will have to set DAG2 & DAG3 to start on the same schedule as DAG1 and they will need to constantly poke DAG1 till it's finish. It will work just not very optimal.

Comment: Thanks Much!  I'm having challenges in implementing this.  I cannot modify the DAG1 code as it is owned by.a different team. Is there a way to add the TriggerDagRunOperator in my DAG2 and DAG3 files? Appreciate any inputs! Thanks in advance!

Comment: So this is a whole different question. In that case all you can do is using `ExternalTaskSensor` - it will not give you the exact functionality you are really after because you have no way of knowing when DAG1 is finished. You will need to start DAG2, DAG3 on the same schedule as DAG1 and constantly check if DAG1 is finished.

Comment: Thanks Much for your immediate reply. Want to make sure. Thanks again!